# How to rigorously argue that supremum of a integrable nonnegative supermartingale $M^n$ is finite

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

I want to prove that that supremum of a integrable nonnegative supermartingale $M^n$ is finite.

By the martingale convergence theorem, we know that $\lim_n M^n = M$ almost surely with $E[M]<\infty$. I think we can argue that finite limit implies finite supremum but M being a random variables confuses me. Can we make this argument even though $M$ is a random variable, not a fixed number?

Comment: Please don't label added context as an attempt.  What matters is context, which you added, with respect to your thoughts. Well done.  If you'd like to separate your context from the question, **Context** is sufficient.

Comment: $EM <\infty$ implies $M <\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your comment.  I understand your point. Is it rigorous to argue that $M^n$ has a finite limit and so a finite supremum as $M<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, that is valid.